# Optimizing correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with the following relevant attributes:

- companies (id)
- products (id, product_name, type, price, and launch date)
- sales (id, product_id, week_number, week_sales_amount)

I want to put together an "index" comparing how well each product (by type and price point) sold in its first X weeks since launch.

So far I have this:

```
select 
    product.product_name, ...
    round(product_sales.total_sales / (product_sales_by_price_and_type.total_sales / product_sales_by_price_and_type.num_products),4) as 'Index'
from 
    products
inner join companies (on id...)
left join 
    (
        select sum(week_sales_amount) as total_sales, product_id, ...
        from sales
        where sales.week_number between 'A' and 'B' 
        group by sales.product_id
    ) product_sales

left join 
    (
        select company.id, product.price, product.type, sum(sales.week_sales_amount as total_sales, count(distinct product.id) as num_products
        from products
        inner join companies
        left join sales
        where sales.week_number between 'A' and 'B' 
        group by companies.id, products.price, products.type 
        having count(sales.week_number >= 'B') 
    ) product_sales_by_price_and_type
```

The above works fine until I need to add additional criteria to calculate a rolling index, e.g. for each product, only compare to sales of other products (for the same company, product price, and product type) within x years of its launch date.  To satisfy that, I converted the left join into two queries, i.e.:

```
(
select sum(sales.week_sales_amount) as total_sales
        from products
        inner join companies
        left join sales
        where sales.week_number between 'A' and 'B'
        **and products.launch_date >= (outer products.launch_date - 2 years)**
        and companies.id = ...
        and products.price = ...
        and products.type = ...
        group by companies.id, products.price, products.type 
        having count(sales.week_number >= 'B') 
    ) product_sales_by_price_and_type
```

*Of course I have to do the same get the count (so I've gone from one left join to two queries.*

Is there a better approach?

In MySQL, if I run the original query with the left joins, it has a duration of 0.34 seconds and a fetch time of 0.07 sec (I'm running against a local datebase).

With the correlated subqueries, the duration is actually faster, at 0.17 seconds, but the fetch time goes up to almost 60 seconds.

Any suggestions how I can optimize this?

Comment: If the sub-query is correlated, why do you need the `GROUP BY`? Also, why are there no `ON` clauses for your joins?

Comment: Ah, you're right, I do not need those.  They were copied over from the joins.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.